File upload using IFormFile at application services work with swagger ui，but cant work with blazor page
I have implemented a function in my ABP application service:
public async Task CreateVideoNewsAsync(string VideoName, IFormFile VideoFile)

The function works fine when calling the Swagger interface. However, when using the Blazor interface, I created a CreateModal.cshtml file with the following content:
@model CreateModalModel
@inject IStringLocalizer<tennisResource> L
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<abp-dynamic-form abp-model="News" asp-page="/News/CreateModal">
    <abp-modal>
        <abp-modal-header title="@L["NewNews"].Value"></abp-modal-header>
        <abp-modal-body>
            <abp-form-content />
        </abp-modal-body>
        <abp-modal-footer buttons="@(AbpModalButtons.Cancel|AbpModalButtons.Save)"></abp-modal-footer>
    </abp-modal>
</abp-dynamic-form> 


The corresponding CreateModal.cshtml.cs file contains the following code:
namespace huake.tennis.Web.Pages.News
{
    public class CreateModalModel : tennisPageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public CreateNewsViewModel News{ get; set; }
        private readonly ICourtAppService _courtAppService;

        public CreateModalModel(
            ICourtAppService courtAppService)
        {
            _courtAppService = courtAppService;
        }

        public void OnGet(string iVideoName, IFormFile iVideoFile)
        {
            News = new CreateNewsViewModel
            {
                VideoName = iVideoName,
                VideoFile = iVideoFile,
            };
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            //将News.VideoFile实例化
            await _courtAppService.CreateVideoNewsAsync(News.VideoName, News.VideoFile);
            return NoContent();
        }

        public class CreateNewsViewModel
        {
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public required string VideoName { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("上传文件")]
            public IFormFile VideoFile { get; set; }
        }
    }
}


In debugging, I can see that News.VideoFile is not null when calling the await _courtAppService.CreateVideoNewsAsync(News.VideoName, News.VideoFile); function. However, the system throws an error with the following message:
2024-05-13 10:04:31.402 +08:00 [ERR] ---------- RemoteServiceErrorInfo ----------
{
  "code": null,
  "message": "您的请求无效！",
  "details": "验证过程中检测到以下错误。\r\n - The VideoFile field is required.\r\n",
  "data": {},
  "validationErrors": [
    {
      "message": "The VideoFile field is required.",
      "members": [
        "videoFile"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Can anyone help me identify the issue?

If you have cshtml, that's not blazor, But rather mvc or RazorPages. It doesn't help you to solve the problem, but helps you to target the right audience on SO.
